# $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(x,y)=(x+y,xy)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(x,y)=(x+y,xy)$, Then I need to know  which of the following are true statement/statements?

1. $f$ is not differentiable at origin.
2. The derivative of $f$ is not invertible except on the set $y=x$

   This I wrote true as I saw $\det M= 0$ on this set.where $M$ is the jacobian of $f$
3. The inverse image of each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under $f$ has at most two elements

   I have no idea.
4. $f$ is surjective.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: can $f$ be surjective? this part should not be so difficult..

Comment: why down vote :O

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(a,b)=(a+b,a-b)$, which is an invertible linear map on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (it's a simple scale of $\sqrt{2}$ and a rotation through an angle of $45$ degrees.) Then $f\circ g(a,b)=(2a,a^{2}-b^{2})$. If you want to solve $f\circ g(a,b)=(x,y)$, then $a=x/2$ and $b^{2}=y-(x/2)^{2}$, which has at most two solutions. It has no solutions if $y < (x/2)^{2}$; it has one solution if $y=(x/2)^{2}$; and it has two solutions if $y > (x/2)^{2}$. You can easily graph these regions, and then rotate them back to the original coordinate system to see that you're dealing with a rotated parabola.

Comment: $(a,b)=f(x,y)\implies (x+y,xy)=(a,b)\implies x(a-x)=b$ solving $\implies$ $x$ has two possible values. are they asking this in (3). please help me.